# Codebehind is not calling through ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i have a dropdown in which when i select a value in dropdown it should move to the method in codebehind and perform the operation.In my case it is not moving to the codebehind .My aim is to make dropdown a dependent pls help me to solve the issue.

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbField" runat="server" onfocus="setFocus()" CausesValidation="true">
             </asp:DropDownList>
```

Ajax:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type ="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#<%=cbField.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                  $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "GmasField.ascx/cbField_Dependent",
                      data: "{}",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                     async: true,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (msg) {
                         $('#myDiv').text(msg.d); 
                    }
               })
               return false;
             });
         });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it but have you added the WebMethodAttribute to the method you have defined on the code behind?

You seem to have a method in the code-behind called cbField_Dependent()

So just add the attribute like the first line below I think.

```
[WebMethod]
public void cbField_Dependent() {
  // 
}
```

Comment: No Pls tell me how to do it

Comment: I've added an example; if you don't have the [WebMethod] attribute then I am fairly sure that is at least part of your problem.

Comment: i have add Webmethod attribute and namespace.But still issue is not solved

Comment: What is the response of the request that is made (look in your network tab in your browser of choice, what message does it return?)

Comment: Also what is the signature of your method, is it static (I don't remember whether it matters or not, but might be good to know)

Comment: If i add static an object reference is required for non static field,method

Comment: What does the response return?

Comment: it is not calling the server side.if i add static it throws object reference is required for non static field,method

Comment: Have you debugged your click handler on the client side then? if there is no request to the server full stop then that is another part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article, this show step by step method to call web method.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/call-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-jquery/